# How can I add a default image on elementor MEDIA control?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, elementor

I'm developing an elementor widget as a plugin. I don't want the default elementor placeholder image. I want to add a default image from my plugin dir (assets/img/placeholder.png) on elementor control. Now how can I add my image as a default?

```
$repeater->add_control(
        'ferdaussk_team_profile_image',
        [
            'label' => esc_html__( 'Choose Image', 'ferdaussk' ),
            'type' => Controls_Manager::MEDIA,
            'default' => [
                'url' => \Elementor\Utils::get_placeholder_image_src(),
            ],
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `plugin_dir_url(__DIR__) . 'assets/img/placeholder.png'` in `'url'`.

```
$repeater->add_control(
  'ferdaussk_team_profile_image',
  [
    'label' => esc_html__( 'Choose Image', 'ferdaussk' ),
    'type' => Controls_Manager::MEDIA,
    'default' => [
      'url' => plugin_dir_url(__DIR__) . 'assets/img/placeholder.png',
    ],
  ]
);
```